# How to format a matrix system of equations in LATEX

Tags: equations, formatting, matrices

I currently have the following code for a system of equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

    \newcommand{\dpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

    \AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\everymath{\displaystyle}} % \displaystyle systems of equations

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        m\dpartial{u}{T} & m\dpartial{u}{p} \\ 
        -m\left(T\dpartial{R}{T} + R\right) & V - mT\dpartial{R}{p} 
    \end{bmatrix}
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{T} \\ 
        \dot{p} 
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{Q} - p\dot{V} + \dot{m}(h-u) - m\dpartial{u}{\phi}\dot{\phi}  \\
        \dot{m}RT + mT\dpartial{R}{\phi}\dot{\phi} - p\dot{V} 
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, this is the result:

[image]

Therefore, my question is whether there is a way to format the system of equations, such that the vector containing the derivatievs of T and p can have the same height as its adjacent matrices.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding `\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}}` to elements of vector:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand{\dpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\everymath{\displaystyle}} % \displaystyle systems of equations

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        m\dpartial{u}{T} & m\dpartial{u}{p} \\
        -m\left(T\dpartial{R}{T} + R\right) & V - mT\dpartial{R}{p}
    \end{bmatrix}
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{T}\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}} \\
        \dot{p}\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{Q} - p\dot{V} + \dot{m}(h-u) - m\dpartial{u}{\phi}\dot{\phi}  \\
        \dot{m}RT + mT\dpartial{R}{\phi}\dot{\phi} - p\dot{V}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Considering to @Mico comment, you will get better looking matrices and vector by inserting some vertical space between their rows. This you can achieve on many ways, for example:

- by terminate rows with `\\[2ex]`
- by inserting `\addlinespace` determined in the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand{\dpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\everymath{\displaystyle}} % \displaystyle systems of equations

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        m\dpartial{u}{T} & m\dpartial{u}{p} \\
        \addlinespace
        -m\biggl(T\dpartial{R}{T} + R\biggr) & V - mT\dpartial{R}{p}
    \end{bmatrix}
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{T}\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}} \\
        \addlinespace
        \dot{p}\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{Q} - p\dot{V} + \dot{m}(h-u) - m\dpartial{u}{\phi}\dot{\phi}  \\
        \addlinespace
        \dot{m}RT + mT\dpartial{R}{\phi}\dot{\phi} - p\dot{V}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- by use of `\makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand{\dpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\everymath{\displaystyle}} % \displaystyle systems of equations

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{bmatrix}
        m\dpartial{u}{T} & m\dpartial{u}{p} \\
        -m\biggl(T\dpartial{R}{T} + R\biggr) & V - mT\dpartial{R}{p}
    \end{bmatrix}
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{T}\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}} \\
        \dot{p}\vphantom{\dpartial{u}{p}}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{Q} - p\dot{V} + \dot{m}(h-u) - m\dpartial{u}{\phi}\dot{\phi}  \\
        \dot{m}RT + mT\dpartial{R}{\phi}\dot{\phi} - p\dot{V}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So that's where the `\vphantom` command is used. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1- :-) I would consider creating a bit more vertical whitespace by loading the `booktabs` package and inserting `\addlinespace` directives after each instance of `\\`. Additionally, the parentheses generated by `\left(` and `\right)` seem a bit too tall; I'd go with `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you. This improve matrix looks. I will edit my answer answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`, you can add delimiters in the preamble of the array. You don't need `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand{\dpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{NiceArray}{[cc][c]}
m\dpartial{u}{T} & m\dpartial{u}{p} & \dot{T} \\  
-m\left(T\dpartial{R}{T} + R\right) & V - mT\dpartial{R}{p} & \dot{p} 
\end{NiceArray}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{Q} - p\dot{V} + \dot{m}(h-u) - m\dpartial{u}{\phi}\dot{\phi}  \\
\dot{m}RT + mT\dpartial{R}{\phi}\dot{\phi} - p\dot{V} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]